# Passing 'NSString *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double')

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I try to retrieve latitude and longitude values from Google Maps SDK, well I am using this :

```
NSString *lati = [end_loc objectForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *longi = [end_loc objectForKey:@"lng"];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lati, longi);
```

But in the line of **marker.position** I am getting this error :

```
Passing 'NSString *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double')
```

Any ideas on how I can solve it ?

Comment: Read the error message? - Look up the documentation of CLLocationCoordinate2DMake()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because CLLocationCoordinate2DMake wants CLLocationDegrees as a type of parameters, and you pass NSStrings (or what is in end_lok for key lat/lon).

You could try to solve it like this:

```
NSString *lati = [end_loc objectForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *longi = [end_loc objectForKey:@"lng"];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lati doubleValue], [longi doubleValue]);
```